# Problem with displaying an image as a background on a div in react

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

I have this problem where the image just won't be displayed as the background of the div.
even though the image is displayed normally when put in an image tag.

```
<div className="card text-dark " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${mainImg})` }}>
                        {/* <img
                            className="card-img"
                            src={mainImg}
                            alt="Creative Manner Design Lorem Ipsum Sit Amet Consectetur dipisi?"
                        /> */}
</div>
```

I have checked the css and the syntax with and various ai tools for help and just couldn't solve this problem.

i have changed the syntax to this:
 `<div className="card text-dark" style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + { mainImg } + ")" }}>`

or this

`<div className="card text-dark " style={{ backgroundImage:` url(/${mainImg}) `}}>`

`<div className="card text-dark " style={{ backgroundImage:` url(./${mainImg}) `}}>`

still didn't work

Comment: Could you post more of the code please? Where are you getting the `mainImg` from? If you check the inspect element on the page, can you see the url to your image?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="card text-dark" 
     style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${mainImg})`, 
     height: '200px', width: '200px' }}>
</div>
```

Try adding height and width ? Assuming your path should be right.

Answer (score 0):

set your component this way

```
    import React from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const mainImg = 'https://example.com/image.jpg'; // Replace this with your image URL
  return (
    <div className="card text-dark" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${mainImg})`}}>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```